# getting null array while fetching all the documents of a given array of user uid

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to fetch all the user documents of the followers array, which is consist of uid(string).

```
{
    "followers": [
        "GHfd4UbusVUV5Ofo3xU4gH3XDFv2", "W380Qbxq2vUTKuzQdOvdsrFyrjb2"
    ],
    "followings": [
        "GHfd4UbusVUV5Ofo3xU4gH3XDFv2"
    ]
```

I am sending the follower array directly as idArray
I am using the below code:

```
router.get('/a/:idArray', (req, res) => {
User.find({ uid: { $in : req.params.idArray}})
    .then(users => {
        res.json(users);
        console.log('array',users);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

But i am getting null array. Where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: How are you passing the array to the get from the client side?

Comment: please check the question again. I have updated it. @JimB.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass array like this `["W380Qbxq2vUTKuzQdOvdsrFyrjb2", "GHfd4UbusVUV5Ofo3xU4gH3XDFv2"]` into the `GET` request.

Convert your array in the client side to comma separated values and pass as a query string

`/a?idArray=W380Qbxq2vUTKuzQdOvdsrFyrjb2&idArray=GHfd4UbusVUV5Ofo3xU4gH3XDFv2`

Answer (score 0):

For passing complex objects, having to url-encode everything can get to be a pain, so while @front_end_dev's answer is correct, if your API gets more complicated you may want to move to passing data in the body of a POST request:

```
router.post('/a', (req, res) => {
    User.find({ uid: { $in : req.body.uids }})
        .then(users => {
            res.json(users);
            console.log('array',users);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

body would look like:

```
{
    uids: [
        "GHfd4UbusVUV5Ofo3xU4gH3XDFv2", 
        "W380Qbxq2vUTKuzQdOvdsrFyrjb2"
    ]
}
```